# Script to automate different REST API CURL commands asynchronously

Tags: rest, curl, load, load-testing

I'm looking for best scripting language or a model script suitable to automate the following REST API calls. The input to calls is JSON input.

1. POST on REST API with JSON input
2. Extract 'ID1' from Response Data and pass it to next GET call
3. Extract another 'ID2' from the above GET call and pass it to next GET call
4. Extract 'Elapsed Time' from next GET call
5. Measure the latency for concurrent user runs 
   I appreciate if someone point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it:

1. is free and open source
2. has GUI so you won't have to learn any language
3. comes with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) to you will be able to easily convert your curl calls into a JMeter test plan
4. provides [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to generate arbitrary HTTP requests
5. provides [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to manipulate request headers
6. provides [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) to extract data from REST responses

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide to get started.